# Python to Excel

Tags: python, docplex, excel, cplex-python-api

Using DOcplex module an optimization problem is solved.

There are many decision variables in the solution, for the validation of the mathematical model I want to check them.

How can I write the solution (decision variables) to Excel worksheets?

Answer (score 7):

A great option is to use the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html) library, and specifically [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) is what you need.

I suggest you use one column per variable index, and one line per non zero variable.

Here is one way of puting the solution into dataframe form. Something like:

```
variable_name = []
variable_value = []
for x in variables:
   if value(x)>0:
      variable_name.append(x)
      variable_value.append(value(x))

keys = ["variable_name", "variable_value"]
values = [variable_name, variable_value]
df_solution = DataFrame(dict(zip(keys,values)),columns=keys)
df_solution.to_excel("my_solution.xlsx")
```

Comment: I tried this option but the variables in the solution are not in dataframe form.So that doesn't work. Even so, thank you :)

Comment: Well of course they are not in dataframe form. But it is very easy to put them into this form :)

Comment: How can I put my variables into dataframe form?

Answer (score 4):

I have used [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) several times to create or alter excel files. It is quite easy if one is familiar with Python.
With this module you can iterate through your variables and write its value to a cell.

Comment: I use this too. Formatting with it can be a pain but I've found that a few helper functions I carry around with me are worth a few minutes to make.

Answer (score 1):

There are both pandas and openpyxl recommendations here. In my experience, if you want to go read and write on the cell level, or do more than basic analysis, use Pandas. Use openpyxl If you want to script basic excel functions